# Performance and security in C++ when avoiding use of pointer

Tags: c++, performance, security, stack, encapsulation

I'm trying to create a class in C++ with an idea of absolute encapsulation and efficiency for the sake of practice. In my case this means every data member is supposed to be inside the class with no pointers pointing outside (e.g. to dynamically allocated storage).

For example, I'm using

```
char name [10];
```

instead of

```
std::string name;
char* name;
```

My idea is that objects of the class are created as **completely enclosed blocks** on the stack. As well as that performance is increased, since, if I remember correctly, access to the stack is considerably faster than to the heap.

*Am I correct in those assumptions?*

*And is this idea of absolute encapsulation sensible outside practice?* (For example to ensure safety, since there seems to be no risk of memory mismanagement or buffer overflow)

Comment: _"... if I remember correctly, access to the stack is considerably faster than to the heap...."_ from the CPU's point of view it's just memory.  How you access memory is more important that what a region of memory is notionally called.  Also remember that (a) global variables are bad (for a given value of bad) and (b) the static by default is a limited resource (usually about 1M), (c) you can overrun `char name [10];` eg `name[10];`  In summary an artificial restriction that provides no actual benefit.

Comment: You have to handle buffer overrun with fixed-size "container", whereas `std::string`/`std::vector` can grow.

Comment: Stack size is more limited than heap in practice.

Comment: Something to keep in mind, this method is far more limiting, in that you have set maximum lengths that aren't amenable to run-time adjustment. It is possible to have something like: struct foo { unsigned name_length; unsigned pwd_length; unsigned domain_length; }; and you over-allocate the foo object to be immediately followed by the character arrays, I do admit such structures are painful to deal with (due to having to calculate the base address of each character array).

Comment: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-performance and especially [Per.6: Don’t make claims about performance without measurements](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rper-measure)

Comment: For your `char`/`std::string` example, Small String Optimization is a thing in c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> access to the stack is considerably faster than to the heap

This is false: an access to memory is an access to memory. Two things might have confused you here.

First, it is true that different types of memory can be accessed at different speeds. For example, the disk is usually the slowest (without talking about networking, which complicates things even further), while registers are usually the fastest. In between is the main memory, or RAM, where both the stack and the heap live. And then you can have caches, different types of disks, and so on.

Second, stack allocation is indeed faster than heap allocation, just because the allocation scheme is simpler. With the stack, as the name implies, you can only allocate and deallocate at the end, meaning you need to follow a specific order. With the heap, you can allocate pretty much anywhere, meaning that you can deallocate at any point and in any order. This implies some kind of management of the memory that comes with its own problems, for example fragmentation.

> is this idea of absolute encapsulation sensible outside practice?

First of all, only using the stack is impossible in practice simply because of its limited size. While this size can vary in practice, it's unlikely to be more than 8MB currently. As soon as you need to load a file larger than that, you cannot do it on the stack.

However, even if stack size was practically unlimited, you still need to deallocate things in the reverse order that you allocated them, otherwise it no longer is a stack. Many things are infeasible that way. For example, as soon as you want interactivity, you need some sort of event processing (to respond to user input), and this is usually done with a queue, which is like the opposite of a stack. Sure you could allocate an insanely large queue, but that's infeasible in practice. Another example that comes to mind is networking. If you want to deal with multiple connections at once (like a web browser for example), you need to deal with the memory associated to each one independantly. Again, you could allocate an insane amount of memory to each connection, but again, that's infeasible in practice.

Also, note that *encapsulation* does not mean "no pointers to dynamically allocated memory". Instead, "hidden memory management" would be closer to the meaning of this concept.